# How do I return a UIImage inside a function?

Tags: ios, swift

I have a class which is my model to get the text value and images to display.

I am trying to return the textvalue and image to my controller to display it on the UILabel and ImageView but for some reason my function keeps generating errors like, return type is not specified or "Variable 'image' used before being initialized"

Can someone please tell me what is the best way to write this function? The two arrays will be fixed and will always have at least one value.
Also I would like to know what would be the way if the array could potentially be a nil.

```
struct LoginCardSwipe{
    let loginText = ["Discover new and interesting people near by" , "Swipe Right to meet new" , "Hey how are you?", "Discover new and interesting people near by" , "Discover new ", " Heoosadda" ]

    let loginImage = ["tinder1", "tinder2", "tinder1", "tinder2", "tinder2"]
    var currentIndex = 0
    mutating func getCardValueRight() -> String{
        currentIndex += 1
        if currentIndex >= 0, currentIndex < loginText.count {
            let textValue = loginText[currentIndex]
            return textValue
        } else{
            return ""
        }
    }

    mutating func getCardImageRight() -> UIImage{
        currentIndex += 1
        var image: UIImage?
        if currentIndex >= 0, currentIndex < loginText.count {
            let cardImage = loginImage[currentIndex]
            image = UIImage(named: cardImage)
        }
        return image!
    }

    mutating func getCardValueLeft() -> String{
        currentIndex -= 1
        var textValue: String
        if currentIndex >= 0, currentIndex < loginText.count {
            textValue = loginText[currentIndex]
            return textValue
        }else{
            return ""
        }
    }

    mutating func getCardImageLeft() -> UIImage{
        currentIndex -= 1
        var image: UIImage
        if currentIndex >= 0, currentIndex < loginText.count {
            let cardImage = loginImage[currentIndex]
            image = UIImage(named: cardImage)!
        }

        return image
    }
}
```

Comment: There's only one error and it's in your last function. Think about the state of `image` if the `if` statement is false. Though the code in `getCardImageRight` will crash if the `if` statement is false.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The correct implementation for 2 image left & right methods

```
mutating func getCardImageRight() -> UIImage? {
    currentIndex += 1
    if currentIndex >= 0, currentIndex < loginText.count {
        let cardImage = loginImage[currentIndex]
        return UIImage(named: cardImage)
    }
    return nil
}
```

//

```
mutating func getCardImageLeft() -> UIImage? {
    currentIndex -= 1
     if currentIndex >= 0, currentIndex < loginText.count {
        let cardImage = loginImage[currentIndex]
        return UIImage(named: cardImage)
    }

    return nil
}
```

//

and when use

```
if let left = strInstance.getCardImageLeft() {

}
```

as force - unwrapping a value that may be nil will result in a crash

Comment: Why are you force-unwrapping `UIImage(named:)` in a method that returns an optional?

Comment: @Sh_Khan also I can not return nil, I have tried that before.

Error - Nil is incompatible with return type 'UIImage'

Comment: Did you replaced the 2 methods as in answer especially the return **-> UIImage?**